# the_permalink() returning only slug

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

On my wordpress site, `the_permalink()` returns only the slug, and not the full URL. So, for example, for the page:

```
https://www.example.com/hello-world
```

`the_permalink` would return `/hello-world/`.

This works most of the time as `the_permalink()` is used mostly for links within the site, but it causes problems when I use them for share links.

From docs and other examples, I think `the_permalink()` is supposed to return the full URL. Why is it returning something different for me? I don't think anyone has added a filter for the function.

Comment: Do you have another function somewhere that is applying a *filter* the [`the_permalink`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_permalink)? There is a filter for it that runs at the end of the function

Comment: I grepped for it and didn't find one. I certainly didn't add one either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the reason is that I have the "Relative URL" plugin installed, which calls `wp_make_link_relative()` to make everything relative! That explains everything.